# Require in reactjs is throwing cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, require

Edit: Noob Helps here.

I checked a lot of similar questions already and none of them are quiet the same.

React is receiving an array of object from express. loop thru, get each object image link and add it to the source.

This is the original code

```
  {this.state.currentTemplates.map((items, pos) => {
            return (
              <div className={`template `}>
                <img src={require(`${items.link}1.jpg`)} />
                <p>{items.name}</p>
                <div className="buy">buy</div>
              </div>
```

if image exist like this, require will find it and it will work.

but if i send a request to another function to check if image exist first, like a try catch.

```
 <div className={`template `}>
//sending url to another function. Also I can put the function outside of class and just call without 'this' and it does not make any difference.

                <img src={this.checkUrl(`${items.link}1.jpg`)} />
                <p>{items.name}</p>
                <div className="buy">buy</div>
```

Ex:

```
 checkUrl(url) {
       console.log(url); // receive right url '../products/templates/a.jpg'
       try {  
 // try will require the right url but module cannot found it and it goes to catch. Now I can also put it in a variable var a= require(url) and it does not make a difference

          require(url);
console.log("it works "); // it never gets to here.
          return url; // this may not work once returned but it does not get to here.
      }catch(e) {
//react jump to catch with "cannot find module '../products/templates/a.jpg'"
         console.log(e);
       }
}
```

I got Error: require cannot find module '../products/templates/1.jpg'

interesting thing. If i add the product folder inside the component folder with the templates.jsx file. it works.

Also it is not a syntax error, i may have made a typo replicating the issue here.

Recap: if I call require(url) straight from the src jsx, it found image.

If i pass url to another function to do a try catch. Console log the right url but require throw cannot find module.

is this a react limitation? is there a work around ? am i approaching this thee wrong way ?

Comment: try without require why do use require  it should work without require  this shape                 <img src={${items.link}1.jpg`)} />

Comment: I tried that and here is what I got. Image simply does not display but in inspect, I see the right url. '<img src="../products/moveItFitness/1.jpg">' but in Network tab. 1.jpg has this error message. " Cannot GET /products/moveItFitness/1.jpg ". I think I will have to put image in the same folder. It does not seem to be able to go back 2 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching it in the wrong way, your images MUST be served, not requiring it as a module. It must be included in your static assets, or an external url served in other server. This is the common pattern, please don't complicate it.

If you have a public folder, just put it there like in the

```js
public/images/image1.jpeg
```

Then in your code you can access it by:

```js
<img src="/images/image1.jpeg" />
```

Provided you serve the assets.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is interesting. You know that is how i originally wrote it(Coming from html , css , pure js background. ) but it does not work. Image simply do not load. After researching I found that react either require the image or I have to import it. Because the links information are coming from a database, I could not hard code, it had to be dynamic. But I will try it again, just in case I was drunk. An External URL  works that way tho. Tested it

Comment: If so, then just put the link directly to the src="link-here". It is not need to be required. the <img> element just loads the image by fetching it through the url. See for example, if you have 1,000 images then that needs to be in your folder because you need to require it for it to be used? The answer is NO! That's why you don't require image, just the link. You understand what I mean?

Comment: ok come down bro. I will try it and give you credit if it works. Thanks for the fast reply tho. Just to be sure, you mean src={items.url}   will work fine.

Comment: ok this did not solve it the way I wanted it but it works and That is the only way. The files HAVE to be in the public folder. It cannot be outside of the Public folder or it will not work which is where I wanted to add my products files for management

Answer (score 1):

look at first check the where the folder is line path to check the  is the path that provides true or not  the used this `<img src={`${items.link}1.jpg`} />` without require 
again if the image is external image  found on web there will be no problem but if the is internal storage the check your correct path

Comment: I tried that and here is what I got. Image simply does not display but in inspect, I see the right url. '<img src="../products/moveItFitness/1.jpg">' but in Network tab. 1.jpg has this error message. " Cannot GET /products/moveItFitness/1.jpg ". I think I will have to put image in the same folder. It does not seem to be able to go back 2 steps.